# I get Error 403 Forbidden when try to reach Pastebin links

Tags: c#, webclient

Since yesterday when I try to get some text from Pastebin I get the "Error 403 Forbidden" message.
My current code which worked for months:

```
//...
    var url_main = "raw_pastebin_link";
    var client_main = new WebClient();
    using (var stream_main = client_main.OpenRead(url_main))
    using (var reader_main = new StreamReader(stream_main))
    {
    //Some code
    }
//...
```

I try to add some headers like this but the problem is still.

```
//...
            var client_main = new WebClient();
            client_main.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/6.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36.");
            using (var stream_main = client_main.OpenRead(url_main))
//...
```

Maybe the Pastebin servers banned my IP?
(The links are good when I open them in a browser)
Is there any way to solve this error?
Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your pastebin is public or unlisted

Comment: Yes, i checked all the links are public

Comment: Add header with this method `client_main.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Only a Header!");`

Comment: tried, I got the same error message

Answer (score 0):

I have recently also experienced this and this is the solution I am currently using in my project.

```
using System.Net.Http;

string urlData = String.Empty;
WebClient WebClient = new WebClient();

// Add headers to impersonate a web browser. Some web sites 
// will not respond correctly without these headers
WebClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12");
WebClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
WebClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-gb,en;q=0.5");
WebClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");

urlData = WebClient.DownloadString("enter your URL here");
```

Let me know if this worked for you!

Comment: After 2 days the original code works again. I think the Pastebin's servers temporary banned my ip.

Comment: Alright nice. might want to add some limitations to the amount of times the URL gets called because your IP probably got temp banned because it requested too many times within a specific time period